# Are nested classes and member classes the same thing?

Tags: java, class, jls

Can the Java terms *nested class* and *member class* be used interchangeably or not?

From the JLS:

> A nested class is any class whose declaration occurs within the body of another class or interface.
>
> […]
>
> A member class is a class whose declaration is directly enclosed in the body of another class or interface declaration

I'm thinking the term member classes might not include *anonymous classes* and *local classes*, but this is just guesswork on my part.

Comment: I think you're probably right. Classes defined not as top level within a main class but, for example, as an anonymous class within a method, would be nested classes, but not member classes (I would think).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a good quote from [*Chapter 8. Classes*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html):

> Member class declarations describe nested classes that are members of the surrounding class. Member classes may be `static`, in which case they have no access to the instance variables of the surrounding class; or they may be inner classes.

As a bonus quote, [local classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.3) are definitely not member classes:

> A *local class* is a nested class that is not a member of any class [...].

---

```
class Foo {
    // a member class
    class InstanceMember {}
    // a member class
    static class StaticMember {}

    Foo() {
        // not a member class
        class LocalAndNotMember {}
        // not a member class
        Object anonymousAndNotMember = new Object() {};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested classes can include either static or non-static classes, where member classes are the later.  So member classes are a subset of nested classes.

Comment: I think you are incorrect, sir, and are confusing member class with *inner class*. Since an interface inside a class is implicitly static but still called a member interface (in the JLS), I find it unlikely that a static class within another class wouldn't be a member class also. Furthermore static fields and static methods are also members.

Comment: I think your statement 'member classes are a subset of nested classes' *might* be true though for the reason mentioned in the question.